# Will there be blocking problems when using python multi-process and coroutine together?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, coroutine

**First look at the background requirements and realization ideas:**

I want to realize a requirement. I want to send the package as fast as possible in a short time. Considering the problem of GIL lock, I plan to use a multi-process + coroutine solution after online inquiry. The specific idea is: open several processes, a coroutine is opened in each process, and a package function is placed in the coroutine to complete.

Here in the coroutine package, the general method on the Internet is to establish an event loop, encapsulate the package function into a Task, and then use loop.run_until_complete to execute these tasks in a loop until all the tasks are completed. However, I have no limit on the number of packages to be sent, which cannot be determined in advance. How many tasks need to be packaged, so I plan to use loop.run_forever to enable a permanent event loop, and then use run_coroutine_threadsafe to dynamically add the package tasks to it.

**The following are the problems encountered:**
I plan to make a simplified version for debugging, that is, use a subprocess to test, but I ran into a problem:
Now I create a child process in the main function, because the function run_coroutine_threadsafe needs to run in a new thread, so I create the child thread again in the child process, enable the event loop in the child thread, and dynamically in the main thread of the child process To add tasks.
Below is my code. To facilitate debugging, I temporarily commented out the operation of dynamically adding tasks.

```
import urllib
from urllib import parse
import urllib.parse
import json, hashlib, hmac, base64, datetime, time, threading
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp_requests import requests
from threading import Thread
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process


def start_loop(loop):
    print('enter the loop')
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    print("start loop", time.time())
    loop.run_forever()

async def test():
    r = await requests.get('https://www.huya.com/cache.php?m=LiveList&do=getLiveListByPage&tagAll=0&page={}')
    print(r.status)

def processMain():
    print("enter the process")
    loop_detect = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    t_detect = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(loop_detect,))    
    t_detect.start()
    #while True:
    #    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(test(), loop_detect)
    #    time.sleep(0.001)

    t_detect.join()
    print("the subprocess finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('start the program')
    process = Process(target=processMain)
    process.start()
    process.join()
    print("finish")
```

After clicking Run, the result is:

```
start the program
```

The program never exits,which is very strange.I made two attempts:

1. Try to remove the multi-process and use the coroutine directly,that is,directly create a child thread in the main function, the child thread uses run_forever to start the event loop, and dynamically add tasks in the main thread, the result is right.
2. I still use multi-process,and then comment out the loop.runforever in the above code.The result at this time is as follows:

```
    start the program
    enter the process
    enter the loop
    start loop 1623922146.2899957
    the subprocess finished
    finish
    [Finished in 2.2s]
```

So what I want to ask is, why is there a problem when multi-process is enabled, and even if there is a problem, why does it cause statements like entering a loop to not be printed?

I originally guessed whether the console output also enabled the copy after the child process was enabled, so I couldn't see the output, but in this case, why can I use multiple processes alone and see the output of the child process without using a coroutine?
If I want to achieve the requirements mentioned above, how to do it that will be OK？

Comment: "The program never exits,which is very strange" - well, you join on another process, so the program will wait until that process dies. That's what `.join()` does. If that process runs forever, your program will also run forever

Comment: To run this code, we don't need most imports. Please remove them, so we get a [mre] (make it more minimal)

Comment: Next question: where and how do you run this program? For the original program, I get different output: `start the program
enter the process
enter the loop
start loop 1623925909.8452508` as I would expect

Comment: Oh,thanks you for your answer. The code is part of a project, so there are other imports here. And I am really surprised that you have the right output when running the original program. Maybe it is because i run it by sublime, maybe i need to try it in pycharm.Anyway,thank you very much

Comment: I have tried it in Pycharm,well,it works. maybe i should give up sublime

Comment: Maybe Sublime captures only the output of the current application, not of applications started by that program.